# Parsing Open Graph meta properties/tags in ObjectiveC

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook-opengraph

I have an iOS app in objectiveC which uses UIWebView to load a webpage. I want to parse the Open Graph meta tags of that web page -

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Content" />
```

With the following code I can iterate through all of the meta tags and get their content, but how do I check for the meta properties I am interested in?

```
NSString *resultStr = [self.viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      @"(function(){"
                       "var i, metaFields = document.getElementsByTagName(\"meta\"), result = [];"
                       "for (i = 0; i< metaFields.length; i++) {"
                                "result.push({\"content\": metaFields[i].content});"
                       "}"
                       "return JSON.stringify(result);"
                       "})();"
                       ];
NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resultStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
```

For example if I am only interested in the "og:site_name" how do I check for it? I tried "metaFields[i].property" but it seems that properties are not accessible that ways. I want to do something like -

```
"if (metaFields[i].property === \"og:site_name\")"
```

Thanks,

Comment: not sure if this will work in your situation, but have you tried to parse the request? i.e. : - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@" REQUEST: %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"xyzHeader"]); }

Comment: I'm not getting open graph properties in metadata. I've tried getting it through both UIWebView and WKWebView, but no luck. Are there any additional configurations that need to be set in request URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the getAttribute DOM method on the element? Something like:

```
metaFields[i].getAttribute('property')
```

Comment: Also works for WKWebView but will need to use: - (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString 
         completionHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError *error))completionHandler;